# AnimationController with GetView and GetxController

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-getx

Im trying to create a `animationController` with a view that extends `GetView`. I should implement `SingleGetTickerProviderMixin` in my `Getxcontroller` but its deprecated and should use `GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin`. The thing is that its require to implements the following missing method:

```
@override
  Ticker createTicker(TickerCallback onTick) {
    // TODO: implement createTicker
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
```

I dont know how to use that and dont find any solution for that.
Full GetxController:

```
class MainPageController extends GetxController implements GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  Ticker createTicker(TickerCallback onTick) {
    // TODO: implement createTicker
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies(BuildContext context) {
  }
  
}
```

My getx version:

```
get: ^4.6.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, was a simple mistake, only need to change:

```
implements GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
```

for:

```
with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
```